# Run windows phone 8 app on device

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-phone-8

Is there any way I can do it without registering?The account is not registering me as a student and I cannot own a company just for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juts follow this tutorial.   All you have to do is sign in with your Microsoft account and your phone will be "dev unlocked".  No windows phone developer account needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx